# continuous sound on notification alert

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I have successfully set the sound on notification but it occurs as the length of the ringtone. What i want is continuously play the sound until user tap on the notification. I have done this code for the sound.

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
notificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```

Comment: use media player controller

Comment: Will it work when application is not in foreground and not even in background?

Comment: yes it will work , start media player music once the notification reveived and stop it when user tap on notification